# Automator: accepts files and zips folders. Warn about sizes

Tags: file, zip, detection, directory, automator

My goal is to write an user-friendly automator service to e-mail selected files and folders.

To be user-friendly, I need to:

1. Detect the input type. If it is a file, I go to the next step. If it is a folder I zip it first using the name folder_name.zip.
2. Now, I only deal with files (selected or zip version of the folders). If the total size is less than a constant (let's say 20MB) I add the whole lot to the e-mail. If not, I ask the user wether he/she really wants to continue and act accordingly to his/her answer.
3. Cleanup : removing any created zip file.

I am stuck at almost all levels of this workflow (detecting the type of the individual items in input. Conditionally acting depending on the result. Sum up the sizes of all items, conditionally acting on the result).

I could also have two separate actions, one for files, one for folders, but I can't find the "file only" input type.

Comment: what if its files and folders selected

Comment: Well, if there is an action for files only and an action for folders only, it shouldn't be offered to the user when files and folders are selected. The idea is not to get something perfect, but just an action that will make it simple to add files, zipped copies of folders and just issue a warning if the size of the attachments is too large. I know I won't get a warning if I run the workflow several times. That's OK for me.

Comment: There is no files Service input, only specific file types or files & folders.  It would be make more sense to check if there is a single item. If file or folder. Then if its a single file attach it. If is a folder or more than one item zip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.

I have created a [service workflow](http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/?attachment_id=393) for you. Its a proof of concept. And the final stage of adding files to email is left to you. You should also note that there is no checking for packages of applications/bundles. Which on a Mac will be seen as a file but else where as a folder.

There is a lot going on in the service workflow.
(To **test** the workflow in Automator ADD a 'Get Selected Finder Items' as the first Action. But it runs a lot faster when run as a service)

But the basics are:

Service receives selected : files or folders in "finder"

1, **Run Applescript.**

It takes the selected items and passes them onto an applescript that checks the size and then displays a dialogue if all items are larger than 20M. ( note the du command seems to round down some what).
If user hits ok then we move on. If cancel the workflow will stop.
No dialogue will display if less than 20M. It will just move on.

2,**Set value of Variable**

Store the full list in the **Storage** Variable  and pass it on to the next action.

3, **Filter Finder Items**

filter for 'kind' is 'folder'
pass the result to next action.

4, create Archive.

I have left this to save on the desktop. But I suggest you do it to the users temp folder.

pass the result down to the next action. ( path of the zip file if any.)

5,**Set value of Variable**

Stores the path to the zip file  in the **Archive** Variable (if one was created )
***Do not pass it on to the next action.***

6,**Get value of Variable**

(Does not take result of last action.)
Get the **Storage**  Variable value.
pass the result to next action.

7, **Filter Finder Items**

filter for 'kind' is **not** 'folder'
pass the result to next action.

8, **Set value of Variable**

Store the **file** list in the **files** Variable.
....

From here on you have two  Variable.  **file**  and **Archive**

you can use them to send the items they reference files and zip to you email ..

And remember this is just a proof of concept.

Cheers

Comment: I think I am starting to get it, to understand how apple scripts work. I learned many things looking at your workflow. Thanks a lot!